# Como passar imagem de uma ImageView para uma ImageView de outra Activity?

Tags: android

Fiz uma app que pega a imagem da galeria e coloca em uma *ImageView*, até ai tudo certo.
Agora queria pegar esta imagem que esta na *ImageView* e passar para uma *ImageView* de outra *Activity*.

Tentei isso:

**Primeira Activity:**

```
public void sertarImagemEmOutraTela (View v){

    Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
    BitMap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable.getBitMap();
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    byte[] bytes = stream.toByteArray(); 

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("bitmapbytes",bytes);
    startActivity(intent);


}
```

**Segunda Activity:**

```
    imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);


    Intent intent = getIntent();

    Bundle param = intent.getExtras();
    byte[] bytes = param.getByteArray("BITMAP");
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

    imageView.setImageBitMap(drawable);
```

[image: Imagem do erro que aparece na segunda activity]

Comment: O que resultou da tentativa?

Comment: esta dando erro, a imagem não é mostrada na segunda activity.

Comment: Qual é o erro ?

Comment: eu consigo trazer a imagem da galeria e setar no imageview da primeira activity, mais quando eu tento passar para a segunda tela da um erro

Comment: Que método usou para atribuir a imagem à ImageView?

Comment: usei Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);

Comment: juntamente com onActivityResult

Comment: BitMap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable.getBitMap();
Esse trecho de código está correto ? 
BitMap != Bitmap

Comment: pois é, este código esta dando um erro.

Comment: O que eu quis perguntar foi se você usou `imageView.setBackground()` ou usou outro método.

Comment: imageView.setImageBitMap(drawable);

Answer (score 1):

Até onde eu sei o identificador que você colocou no intent para os bytes deve ser o mesmo quando for resgatar seus bytes na segunda activity.

Exemplo, se você colocou `"bitmapbytes"` como identificador para seus bytes em `putExtras("bitmapbytes", bytes)` você devera usar este mesmo identificador para pegar o conteúdo, troque `"BITMAP"` por `"bitmapbytes"` que o problema deve se resolver, e o NullPointerException esta ocorrendo pois você esta usando `decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);` com bytes vazios.

Comment: Samuel seu comentário me ajudou muito...valeu!

Answer (score 1):

Senhores bom dia!
agradeço aos comentários, venho aqui informar que consegui resolver minha duvida.

segue abaixo todo o código, tenho certeza que ajudará outras pessoas que estão começando assim como eu.

primeira activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Uri image;
ImageView img;
Bitmap bitmap_ok;
Button btnImagem1,btnImagem2 ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnImagem1 = findViewById(R.id.btnImagem1);
    btnImagem1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1);
        }
    });

    img = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    btnImagem2 = findViewById(R.id.btnImagem2);
    btnImagem2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            passarImagem();
        }
    });
}

private void passarImagem() {
    img = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Drawable drawable = img.getDrawable();
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
    byte[] imageInByte = stream.toByteArray();

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SegundaTela.class);
    intent.putExtra("imagem",imageInByte);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        image = data.getData();
        try {
            bitmap_ok = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),image);
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap_ok.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);

            img.setImageBitmap(bitmap_ok);
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

segunda activy:

```
public class SegundaTela extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView imgs;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_segunda);
     try {
         Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
         if (bundle != null){
             try {
                 byte[] imageInByte = bundle.getByteArray("imagem");
                 Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageInByte,0,imageInByte.length);
                 imgs = findViewById(R.id.imageView22);
                 imgs.setImageBitmap(bmp);
             }catch (Exception e){}
         }
     }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(this,""+e,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

}